# Bash : Remove all directories except one

Tags: bash

I have folder structure like below

```
├── tmp
   └── Dir1
        |__Dir2
        |__Dir3
        |__Dir4
```

My current working directory is different which is /home/users/aaa from here I want to delete everything inside Dir1 except directory Dir2

I have one working solution which is

```
abc=Dir2
shopt -s extglob             
    `rm -r /tmp/Dir1/!($abc)/`
```

But somehow this solution is not acceptable by team

do you have any other solution for deleting directories except one .

below is my actual code

```
current_date=`date +"%Y_%m_%d"

#remove all containt of folder /tmp/metdata if they are older

shopt -s extglob             
`rm -r /tmp/metdata/!($current_date)/`
```

above solution is working but not acceptable by team:(

removing everything inside "/tmp/metdata/" except folder have name having value  current_date

actually the issue is if there in no folder inside      /tmp/metdata/         it shows below message each time ,I don't want to display this message

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/metdata/!(2020_05_15)/’: No such file or directory
```

can we check any condition before this

any help appreciated

please help

Comment: Your team is probably looking for a less magic and more straight forward approach, like iterating over all the directories with a loop and conditionally deleting

Comment: Remove backticks from `rm` command.

Comment: actually the issue is if there in no folder inside      /tmp/metdata/         it shows below message each time      I don't want to display this message                                                   rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/metdata/!(2020_05_15)/’: No such file or directory

Comment: @Cyrus   actually the issue is if there in no folder inside /tmp/metdata/ it shows below message each time I don't want to display this message rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/metdata/!(2020_05_15)/’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
find /tmp/Dir1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name Dir2 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

```sh
current_date=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d")
find /tmp/Dir1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name "${current_date}" -exec rm -rf {} +
```